# Class vs Instance

Tags: ruby

I am trying to solve https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-class-vs-instance but i get an error.
My code works only when intialAge is less than 0.

*solution.rb:13:in `amIOld': undefined method`<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :age
  def initialize(initialAge)
    if initialAge < 0
        puts "Age is not valid, setting age to 0."
        age = 0
    else
        initialAge = age
    end
    age
  end
  def amIOld()
    if age < 13 
        puts "You are young."
    elsif age.between?(13, 18)
        puts "You are a teenager."
    else 
        puts "You are old."
    end
  end
  def yearPasses()
    age += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: You're setting the parameter to `age`, which is undefined. This is backwards.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `s/initialAge = age/age = initialAge/` :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

`class Person
  attr_accessor :age
    def initialize(initialAge)
        @age = 0
        if initialAge < 0
            puts "Age is not valid, setting age to 0."
            @age = 0
        else
            @age = initialAge
        end
  end
  def amIOld()
    if @age < 13 
        puts "You are young."
    elsif @age.between?(12, 17)
        puts "You are a teenager."
    else 
        puts "You are old."
    end
  end
  def yearPasses()
    @age += 1
  end
end`